# Fuel get the body response on error

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I achieve this? This is the request im doing.

```
Fuel.get(url)
    .timeout(TIMEOUT)
    .body(myRequest.parameters!!, Charsets.UTF_8)
    .responseString() { _, response, result ->
                Log.e("result", "$result")
                when (result) {
                    is Result.Success -> {
                        completionHandler(result.get(), null)
                    }
                    is Result.Failure -> {
                        Log.e("fail", "${response}")
                        completionHandler(null, Error(response.responseMessage))
                    }
                }
            }
```

And the response im getting is:

```
Response : Bad Request
Length : 122
Body : ({"message":"You have already booked that iceCream"})
Headers : (9)
Connection : [keep-alive]
Content-Length : [122]
Content-Type : [application/json; charset=utf-8]
Date : [Thu, 03 May 2018 07:33:21 GMT]
Server : [nginx/1.12.1]
```

I want to return the body message as my error.

Comment: The Fuel request is happening asynchronously and being posted back to the "SAM" on the main thread. There isn't any possibility to use a return statement there. It may be that an observer pattern is required.

Comment: This might help also, [Fuel Samples](https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel). The sample for "Blocking mode" allows the return of the response. But it cannot be called on the main thread.

Comment: Seriously I know that the operation is happening asynch. But since im wating for the response there isn't problem. The body is visible in my response so dont fill me with false information please. I can see the bodyResponse in my fuel response when the operation is caused by a error. So it's there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your code uses `awaitByteArrayResponse` and got `Result<?, FuelError>>` or `FuelError` object, try this:

`val (content, error) = result // Result<?, FuelError>>
val strContent = error.errorData.toString(Charsets.UTF_8)`

Answer (score 5):

As it is mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel/issues/314). You can receive the body with `response.data`, which returns `ByteArray`. Therefore the code could look something like this:

```
val myBody = String(response.data)
```

Another solution would be, disabling the [HTTP Code validator](https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel/blob/master/fuel/src/main/kotlin/com/github/kittinunf/fuel/core/FuelManager.kt#L55), which can be achieved with: `FuelManager.removeAllResponseInterceptors()`

Answer (score 1):

Anyhow I solved It substringing the message out. But Fuel is a big respected library so there is probally another more goodlooking way. But  it's working :)

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across the same issue and did following to get the error message out of the reponse body:

```
// Body : ({"message":"Not allowed to do this!"})
val errorMessage = Json(String(error.response.data)).obj().getString("message")
```

Unfortunately I don't see a more elegant way to do it, since in the source code of [Fuel](https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel/blob/master/fuel/src/main/kotlin/com/github/kittinunf/fuel/core/Response.kt) the `body` attribute is declared as internal.

Answer (score 0):

I was fetching response.data twice and the second time it was when the error occurred.